# How can I combine graphs in Python? (I'm getting multiple graphs.)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

My script generates 8 separate graphs. I want to be able to see all lines on one graph. Also, if prompted I want to produce subplots; so in my case, 8 graphs on 1 sheet.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

columns = input('How many columns? ')
data = np.genfromtxt('csv_file',delimiter=',', dtype = float)

m = 1
p = 0
while p == 0:
    if m < (columns):
        x = [row[0] for row in data]
        y = [row[m] for row in data]
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111, axisbg = 'w')
        ax.plot(x,y,lw=1.3)
        plt.show()
    else:
        p = 1
        m = m+1
```

Comment: Try removing the plt.show() and then just add it at the end.

Comment: @BHBB: I highly recommend looking at how [slicing a numpy array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) works. `data[:, m]` is equivalent to `[row[m] for row in data]`: it extracts the `m`th *column*.

Comment: There's a new library `patchworklib` [check that out](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7MCErZitqjg)

Answer (score 3):

1. The reason you are getting several plots is that in each of your loops, you are calling `plt.figure` which creates a new figure window.  Put this before your loop, and create new `sublot`s within the loop instead.
2. You are simply through values of `m` in `[1, 2, 3, ..., columns]`. This is built in as [`range`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range), where `range(columns)` gives `[0, 1, 2, ..., columns-1]`, so `range(1, columns+1)` will be what you want. You don't need to manually increase `m`, and you don't need to use `p` to stop the loop: these will both happen automatically once `m` has had each value in the range.
3. To get the `m`th column of your data, you can just slice in the "column" dimension, which is the second dimension: `data[:, m]` gives all rows in the `m`th column. The empty `:` means "all rows" and the `m` means "column m". (You can do whole slices just like with lists, but in multiple dimensions). See [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html) and [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) for more info.
4. For the subplots, you have to change the first argument for each plot. You can call it like this: `fig.add_subplot(nrows, ncols, plot_number)`. So you want the `plot_number` to be `m`, in your loop.

All of this together:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.genfromtxt('csv_file',delimiter=',', dtype = float)
columns = data.shape[1] - 1 # a numpy array's `shape` is (rows, columns, etc). I am subtracting the x column.
nrows, ncols = 4, 2 # the product of these should be number of plots (I'm assuming columns=8)

fig = plt.figure()
x = data[:, 0] # same as [row[0] for row in data], and doesn't change in loop, so only do it once.
for m in range(1, columns+1): # this loops from 1 through columns
    y = data[:, m] # same as [row[m] for row in data]
    ax = fig.add_subplot(nrows, ncols, m, axisbg = 'w')
    ax.plot(x, y, lw=1.3)

plt.show() # after loop finishes, only need to show once.
```

Comment: And if you want to plot them all in one plot (no subplot), then delete the `ax = fig.add_subplot` line, and replace `ax.plot` with `plt.plot`, which will automatically plot on the existing figure.

Comment: I'm getting a NameError: name 'data' is not defined.

Comment: That's because I didn't have access to your data, so I had to generate some fake data. Just replace `data` with your own array name. I'll fix it in an edit.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you do the plt.show(), it will show the graph so far and reset it for the next graph.

If you put the plt.show() at the end, there will be one graph with all of the lines in it.

for the subplot option, you're going to need to cycle through add_subplots 241, 242,243,244,245,246,247,248 (and the plt.show() at the end), instead of 111.

Some input at the beginning and a few if statements should see you through!

Comment: Actually running `plt.figure` every time in the loop will still create a new figure window for each plot. `plt.show` isn't an issue.